# How to send a Wowza Stream to Google Cloud Speech API?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, wowza, google-cloud-speech

Wowza gives me rtsp://, rtmp:// and m3u8 streams. I want to send this to Google Cloud Speech API, so it transcribes the streaming on the fly.

This API seems to be able to receive only pure byte representation, and the samples on [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/grpc/src/main/java/com/examples/cloud/speech/StreamingRecognizeClient.java) show how to do it with a file.

How can I achieve this with the Wowza links?

EDIT: My question is different. In the other question I ask for services that offer that functionality and in this I'm talking of Google Cloud Speech specifically, and how to do it with that API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speech-to-text from a LIVE stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453805/speech-to-text-from-a-live-stream)

Comment: There is no need to ask the same question again, you just need to write the code. In a loop get data from the stream and send it to API, then process results. It is not different from recognizing from a file.

Comment: 1. This is not a duplicate
2. If it were that simple as you say I would not be asking.

Comment: The problem you have is how to get data from rtmp stream, not how to send the data to the server, it is exactly the same problem you asked before. The answer on this question will answer your previous question as well. As for your issue, you can find a code demo in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803621/how-to-capture-live-audio-via-rtmp-using-xuggler

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the raw data from a RTSP/RTMP stream would be to use FFMPEG as a client piping the data into your app (FFMPEG providing the transcoding as necessary)

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html

rtmp://[username:password@]server[:port][/app][/instance][/playpath]